# Bash: evaluate a mathematical term?

Tags: bash, math, sh, evaluation

```
echo 3+3
```

How can I evaluate such expressions in Bash, in this  case to 6?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

in shells such as zsh/ksh, you can use floats for maths. If you need more maths power, use tools like `bc/awk/dc`

eg

```
var=$(echo "scale=2;3.4+43.1" | bc)
var=$(awk 'BEGIN{print 3.4*43.1}')
```

looking at what you are trying to do

```
awk '{printf "%.2f\n",$0/59.5}' ball_dropping_times >bull_velocities
```

Comment: any idea about a comment sign for AWk? If I want to have an explicitly stated format for my measurements? Reading just columns can be confusing.

Comment: i don't understand. show what you mean by examples in your question

Comment: POP - power of pipes! `| bc` gets my personal seal of approval

Comment: OP specifically asked about bash

Answer (score 111):

```
echo $(( 3+3 ))
```

Answer (score 37):

`expr` is the standard way, but it only handles integers.

bash has a couple of extensions, which only handle integers as well:

```
$((3+3))  returns 6
((3+3))   used in conditionals, returns 0 for true (non-zero) and 1 for false
let 3+3   same as (( ))
```

`let` and `(( ))` can be used to assign values, e.g.

```
let a=3+3
((a=3+3))
```

for floating point you can use `bc`

echo 3+3 | bc

Comment: expr not only handle integer, following expr just working. expr \( "0.5" \< 20 \),  this expression can be use as if condition directly.

Comment: `$(( ))` is every bit as standard as `expr` is -- having been specified by POSIX.2 since its initial publication in the early 90s -- and much faster to execute. By contrast, `let` is only present in bash for backwards compatibility with 1980s-era ksh. (By contrast, `(( ))` _without the leading `$`_ is a bash extension).

Comment: @zw963, POSIX doesn't require expr to support anything but integers. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html -- any kind of floating-support your copy of `expr` may provide is a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of the [expr](http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html) command as:

```
expr 3 + 3
```

To store the result into a variable you can do:

```
sum=$(expr 3 + 3)
```

or

```
sum=`expr 3 + 3`
```

Comment: I'd like to add (since this post is apparently for Unix beginners) that the backticks on the last line are so the shell evaluates `epr 3 + 3` before sum gets assigned.

Comment: `expr` is an artifact of the 1970s. Ever since the early-90s publication of POSIX.2, shells have been required to support `sum=$((3 + 3))`, which is far more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways - most portable is to use the [expr](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_expr.htm) command:

```
expr 3 + 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the ((3+3)) method is the most rapid as it's interpreted by the shell rather than an external binary.
time a large loop using all suggested methods for the most efficient.

Comment: *nix processes are designed to be extremely lightweight and quick for exactly this reason. So using external binaries is not really that slow considering overall script performance of common usages.

Comment: @hellodanylo it's still an orders-of-magnitude difference. `fork()`+`execve()` is cheaper on UNIX than Windows, sure, but it's still vastly slower than doing operations in the process that's already running. People causally doing expensive things is part of why "overall script performance" is widely considered to be unacceptably slow.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to Dennis, an example of BC-use:

```
$ cat calc_velo.sh

#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat ball_dropping_times`
do
echo "scale=20; $i / 59.5" | bc 
done > ball_velocities
```

Comment: put this into your question. also, you can just use one awk command. It parses files, and takes care of decimal maths. see my answer.

Comment: You're using the redirect operator `>` which truncates (overwrites) the destination file each time. Change that to the append operator `>>` or put the redirection after the `done` instead of after the `bc` like this: `done > ball_velocities`.

Answer (score 1):

One use case that might be useful in this regard is, if one of your operand itself is a *bash* command then try this.

`` echo $(( `date +%s\`+10 )) `` or even `` echo $(( `date +%s\`+(60*60) )) ``

In my case I was trying to get Unixtime 10 seconds and hour later than current time respectively.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of math processing involves floating point processing.

Using **bashj** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/) you can call a java method (with floating point processing, cos(), sin(), log(), exp()...) using simply

```
bashj +eval "3+3"
bashj +eval "3.5*5.5"
```

or in a bashj script, java calls of this kind:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
EXPR="3.0*6.0"
echo $EXPR "=" u.doubleEval($EXPR)

FUNCTIONX="3*x*x+cos(x)+1"
X=3.0
FX=u.doubleEval($FUNCTIONX,$X)
echo "x="$X " => f(x)=" $FUNCTIONX "=" $FX
```

Note the interesting speed : ~ 10 msec per call (the answer is provided by a JVM server).

Note also that *u.doubleEval(1/2)* will provide *0.5* (floating point) instead of *0* (integer)